# Zoho Reports: SQL Query - Finding date and number of days

Tags: sql

Problem Statement: I need to find out Over Due start date and from that i need to calculate number of Over due days. I know how to do for Over due days count, but i am not able to find a way to figure out for Over due start date.

Example: Let us say a customer did not pay for 4th November 2017, 4th December 2017, 4th Jan 2018, 4th Feb 2018. Now for these There were 4 Zero collection records placed in Collections table and 4 records placed in Over Due Collections table with D Flag. Now on 8th Feb Customer Paid an installment then the respective payment record has been placed in Collections table and another record in Over due collections with C flag. Since this payment gets adjusted for 4th November 2017 the Over due start date will be 4th December. Suppose if the customer did not pay then it will be 4th November 2017 as the Over due start date.

I have tables as follows for a Loan Management System:

Schedule (Payment Schedule): Which will have all the Installments, with the dates adn the respective amounts to be paid for each month.

Schema: `LoanNo, Schedule Date, Installment No, Principle, Interest.`

Collections (Payment Collections) for each month which has been collected. Suppose if the payment not received, A record placed with the respective date and with Zero amount. and another record will be placed in Over due collections table with D flag with the respective amounts. If there is any collection happens, then another record will be inserted with the flag C which represents collections.

```
Schema: LoanNo, PaymentReceived Date, Principle, Interest
```

Over Due Collections (Which there will be a record placed if there is a Due)

```
Schema: LoanID, Flag(D/C), Date, Principle, Interest
```

Please do suggest and guide me to write a proper query for this

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , Yes. I need in SQL query only which Zoho Reports Supports.

Comment: "*I need in SQL*" still doesn't tell us which database product you are using. "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database uses "SQL"

Answer (score 0):

it's interesting yet easy problem. you can tackle by calculating running sum of the amount and then compare with total payments by the customer. Take all the records having running sum greater than total payment. and choose minimum date out of it.

let me know if require further help I will give you SQL query. But you should try by your own

Edit 1

this will provide you running_sum

```
_______Subquery1_______
select a.LoanNO,a.Scheduledate,a.Amount,sum(b.amount)run_sum from   
Paymentschedule a 
join PayamentSchedule b 
on a.LoanNo=b.LoanNo and a.ScheduleDate>b.ScheduleDate and 
a.ScheduleDate<=now() group by 1,2,3
```

total collection against loan

```
_______subquery 2_____
select LoanNo,sum(amount)total collection from collection group by 1
```

now

```
 select a.LoanNo,min(ScheduleDate) overduestartdate  from subquery1 join subquery2 on 
 a.LoanNO=b.LoanNO 
and a.run_sum>b.Collection group by 1
```

modify according to your schema

Comment: Thank you for the reply with a guidance. I am trying on it. Not sure how to compare the records, I made two queries as follows but need to compare the records. `select LoanID,  ("PrincipleCollection"+"InterestCollection") as PI from "Collections"`         Another query is:                                                                           
`select LoanID, ("Principle Demand"+"Interest Demand") as PI, "EMI Date" from "RepaymentSchedule" where "EMI Date"<NOW()*`

Comment: A running sum can be done much more efficiently using window functions (`sum(...) over (... order by)`)